# In Android, how to make views transit between screens under viewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

So I have a single activity that controls a viewPager and this viewPager controls five fragments. In one of the fragments, there is an ImageView.

I want this imageView transit to the next page when I do a swipe left. More specifically, the position of this imageView will transit as I am swiping and once the swiping is done and the next fragment layout is completely shown on the screen, this ImageView should be a fixed location in this layout.

Does anybody know how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely not a duplice of that question @SamratDutta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. It might be easier to make it a separate View on top of the pager, perhaps disabled so drags will go through it. and then you need to get a live reading of the position of the page. `onPageScrolled` on [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) is pretty cool and gives you what you need to place elements or do other transitionary effects based on the actual position of the `View`s in your `ViewPager`.